# How to visually enhance MAILTO data submitted text?

Tags: php, html-email, mailto

I am building a website contact form that uses MAILTO to send text that the user submits via the web form. However, the email account that receives the MAILTO text comes in 'ugly' and was wondering if there was a way to get that text into an HTML format to enhance visually without having to rely on some back-end script.

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use "mailto://" to *send* email. Can you share the form html/code?

Comment: [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) Example #4 Sending HTML email

Comment: you mean `<a href="mailto:....">`? You have almost NO control over that at all, and are at the whims of the user-side mail client. and if you're doing `<form action="mailto:...">`, then... DON'T

Comment: Thanks for the comments. To clarify, I'm talking about a "MAILTO FORM" like so: http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa072699mailto.htm . All my customers use Outlook and this is for an intranet website not open to the outside world. Is it OK if I use this method? IF not, should I learn how to do the php method?

Answer (score 0):

you can't format html body using mailto, you need to use mail() function of php,

here is short example:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

more detail: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php